# Is the blue on blue menu bar for this page a deliberate slight or bad humour

Tags: discussion, users

I had to block select the top of the screen to read what the menu options were on this stackexchange.

Is the choice of colour done by some committee that has perfect colour vision or is this supposed to be a satirical statement on bad user interface design?????

[image: Bad colour contrast menu options]

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Yah I'm not seeing this in Chrome 45, IE10, or FF 38.2. For the most part that nav link is white, when the questions tab is open it becomes rgb(124, 172, 213); which is a shade of blue and not ideal but not nearly that bad. I suggest making sure you don't have any extensions active or browser settings messing with active/visited link styles.

Comment: Looks like this for me:
[♬ Blue on blue ♫](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12383864/Photos/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-21%20at%2010.03.04%20PM%20copy.png)

Comment: @DasBeasto I have indeed got NoSquint loaded on Firefox, I had forgotten setting it for SE.   I struggle to tell apart certain shades of blue/purple/green and the blue I have set for the other stackexchanges clashes with UXs radical choices and NoSquint paints all the sub-sites with the same brush.